# Is there a way to figure out the exact sector numbers of clusters “chkdsk” reports as bad?

Tags: chkdsk, bad-sectors, cluster

Recently I run `chkdsk` after it finished it showed 4 clusters in size 4kb are bad, is there any way to know the sector numbers of them?

Comment: Besides knowing for the sake of knowing, what are you trying to do with the info?

Comment: That info going to save my time since the hdd is big in size. Once I know the exact location of those sectors then I will scan them by a fix tool, (reallocate them)